# How To Update Structure of Redux State Persisted In LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, local-storage

I save a part of my Redux state in localStorage so that I can persist it across page refreshes.

How do I update the structure of the state in my localStorage if my Redux state structure changes?

Example:

This is my combineReducer file:

```
// combineReducer

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  usersPage: usersPageReducer,
  form: formReducer
})
```

The original default state in my usersPageReducer looks like:

```
// usersPageReducer.js

defaultUsersPageState = {
  selectedColumns: ["name", "email"],    
}
```

I load and save to localStorage using the following methods:

```
// localStorage.js

export const loadState = () => {
  try {
    const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state')
    if (serializedState === null) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return JSON.parse(serializedState)
  } catch (err) {
    return undefined
  }
}

export const saveState = (state) => {
  try {
    const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state)
    localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState)
  } catch (err) {
    // to define
  }
}
```

In my main file, I subscribe to the store, and save the `usersPage` slice of the state. And I create the store using initial state from localStorage:

```
// main.js
const persistedState = loadState();
const initialState = { ...persistedState };

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
);

store.subscribe(() => {
  saveState({
    usersPage: store.getState().usersPage
  })
})
```

Now imagine I want to change my `usersPageReducer` default state so that it also keeps track of sorting.

```
// usersPageReducer.js

defaultUsersPageState = {
  selectedColumns: ["name", "email"],
  sorting: {"name": "asc"}   
}
```

The above won't work because at the start of the app, we hydrate the redux initial state from localStorage. The old initial state beats out the usersPageReducer `defaultUsersPageState`.

Since localStorage doesn't know about the `sorting` key for `usersPageReducer`, and we never use the default state, the `sorting` key is never added to the redux state.

Is there a way to hydrate the redux store so that it initializes every reducer using it's default state (as if we weren't using localStorage), then spreads the stored state?

Comment: You could make the initial state by deep merging the default state with cached state. Doing so would add the new values to the old cached state.

Comment: Where would I do the merging? 

Would I have to import the default state from every reducer into my `main.js` file? In this case, import `defaultUsersPageState` into `main.js`? That seems like it won't scale in my large application.

Answer (score 2):

There are *two* possible *solution* I can suggest you:-

**1.** Use a variable to keep track of the version of your application (even better *redux-version* ). Now whenever value of this variable is changed, your application will clear-out the user's `LocalStorage` and will use the brand new structure of your redux ( *or its sub-part* ) provided by `defaultUsersPageState` rather than loading the available ( stale ) data from  it.

You can achieve this in multiple ways, mine is

```
// localStorage.js

export const loadState = (CurrVersion) => {
  try {
    // check if version matches or not ... 
    // for first time localStorage.getItem('appVersion') will be null
    if (CurrVersion !== localStorage.getItem('appVersion')){
      localStorage.removeItem('state') // 
       // update the appVersion in LS with current version
      localStorage.setItem('appVersion', CurrVersion) 
      return undefined;
    }
    else{
      const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state')
      if (serializedState === null) {
         return undefined;
       }
       return JSON.parse(serializedState)
      }
   } catch (err) {
      return undefined
  }
}
```

And in `main.js`

```
// change it whenever breaking changes are added and it makes sense 
const CurrVersion = 'MY-APP-VERSION-2.0' 
const persistedState = loadState(CurrVersion);
const initialState = { ...persistedState };

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
);

store.subscribe(() => {
  saveState({
    usersPage: store.getState().usersPage
  })
})
```

2. Check explicitly if the *structure of the persisted data is **changed** or not*. If changed, you can delete the former object and use the default initial state provided which has updated structure. But keep in mind that this check needs to done *recursively (or deeply)*, you may find lodash useful for this.

P.S : Use `npm` packages built for this problem e.g `react-persist` if you have big projects .

Answer (score 0):

The `hash` method can be used to implement this.

Compute the hash of the initial redux keys on the application load and store it in the local storage of the browser

Now calculate the hash of the redux keys present in the application and compare it with the hash present in the browser's local storage.

If they both match, then no action needs to be taken.
If they don't, then either log them out or update the current redux store in the local storage

`sha256` hash can be used to accomplish this

Example

```
import { sha256 } from "js-sha256";
const hash = sha256(digest);
```

INPUT

```
{"auth":"{\"email\":null,\"token\":null,\"error\":null,\"loading\":false,\"authRedirectPath\":\"/dashboard\",\"role\":null,\"clientId\":null,\"registerMessage\":null,\"signupCreds\":{}}
```

OUTPUT

```
29e9cceee4e2df4c53d134dedd0d171939caaab412b17332b3d864693dc62780
```